# Finding Partial Transpose of Matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to find the partial transpose of a density matrix. For example let's suppose the density matrix of bi-partitite system with dimensions 2 and 2.

```
ρ = np.arange(1,17,1)
ρ = np.reshape(ρ,(4,4))
print(ρ)
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8],
       [ 9,  10,  11,  12],
       [ 13,  14,  15,  16]])
```

I want an operation which can result in

```
array([[ 1,  2,  9,  10],
       [ 5,  6,  13,  14],
       [ 3,  4,  11,  12],
       [ 7,  8,  15,  16]])
```

or

```
array([[ 1,  5,  3,  7],
       [ 2,  6,  4,  8],
       [ 9,  13,  11,  15],
       [ 10,  14,  12,  16]])
```

I tried to use the  reshape function to first write the 4x4 matrix into 2x2x2 matrix containing the block of matrix and then try to perform permutation. But I'm not sure how to go about it.

Comment: You are shuffling (2,2) blocks, so you want to start with a reshape to (2,2,2,2).  Then play with `transpose` (or swap) of a couple of those axes.  Then back to (4,4).  This example is small enough that you can play and display results.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with `swapaxes()`:

```
import numpy as np
p = np.arange(1,17)
p = np.reshape(p,(4,4))
p = p.reshape(2, 2, 2, 2).swapaxes(0, 2).reshape(4, 4)
print(p)
```

Output:

```
[[ 1  2  9 10]
 [ 5  6 13 14]
 [ 3  4 11 12]
 [ 7  8 15 16]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a "play around" demonstration:

```
In [35]: arr = np.arange(1,17).reshape(4,4)    
In [36]: arr.reshape(2,2,2,2)
Out[36]: 
array([[[[ 1,  2],
         [ 3,  4]],

        [[ 5,  6],
         [ 7,  8]]],


       [[[ 9, 10],
         [11, 12]],

        [[13, 14],
         [15, 16]]]])
```

Try one pair of axes swap:

```
In [37]: arr.reshape(2,2,2,2).transpose(1,0,2,3)
Out[37]: 
array([[[[ 1,  2],
         [ 3,  4]],

        [[ 9, 10],
         [11, 12]]],


       [[[ 5,  6],
         [ 7,  8]],

        [[13, 14],
         [15, 16]]]])

In [38]: arr.reshape(2,2,2,2).transpose(1,0,2,3).reshape(4,4)
Out[38]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 9, 10, 11, 12],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8],
       [13, 14, 15, 16]])
```

Nope, you want a swap involving an inner dimension:

```
In [39]: arr.reshape(2,2,2,2).transpose(0,2,1,3)
Out[39]: 
array([[[[ 1,  2],
         [ 5,  6]],

        [[ 3,  4],
         [ 7,  8]]],


       [[[ 9, 10],
         [13, 14]],

        [[11, 12],
         [15, 16]]]])

In [40]: arr.reshape(2,2,2,2).transpose(0,2,1,3).reshape(4,4)
Out[40]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  5,  6],
       [ 3,  4,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 13, 14],
       [11, 12, 15, 16]])
```

The other answer swapped 0 and 2.  Transpose and Swap can do the same thing, with just a difference in how the axes are specified.

```
arr.reshape(2,2,2,2).transpose(2,1,0,3).reshape(4,4)
```